# Examples of Koopman operators

Tags: ergodic-theory

This question arises from my [previous one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4831571/find-spectral-measure-of-koopman-operator).

If we have a measure-preserving system $(X, \mathcal B, \mu, T)$ it induces unitary operator $(U_Tf)(x)=f(Tx)$, known as Koopman operator. We can study it in many ways: for example, correspondence between $U_T$ properties and ergodicity.

But the only example I know that can be described explicitly is Koopman operator induced by the circle rotation. So I'm looking for other examples where I can write down Koopman operator explicitly (or find unitary equivalent). What about Markov or Bernoulli shifts? Or may be some other classic measure-preserving systems?

Comment: I think Walters's text *An Introduction to Ergodic Theory* computes these for Markov and for Bernoulli shifts.  For Bernoulli $L^2(\mu)$ splits into the countably many mutually orthogonal $U_T$-invariant subspaces $\mathcal H_i$.  Each $U_T|\mathcal H_i$ is unitarily equivalent to the operator $\phi \mapsto \mathbf e \phi$ on $L^2(\lambda)$, where $\lambda$ is Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$ and $\mathbf e(t) = e^{2\pi i t}$.  This is known as "countable Lebesgue spectrum."  Ergodic Markov shifts also have countable Lebesgue spectrum, I believe.